# Reverse Proxying Google Cloud Storage public URL fails / 404s

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to load some assets from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) onto a website, but I want to use a proxy so if I visit `mysite.com/page/asset.html` I want it to load the content from `http://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/directory/asset.html` without redirecting.

In my apache configs, I am utilizing mod_proxy

```
ProxyPass "/page/asset.html" "http://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/directory/asset.html"
ProxyPassReverse "/page/asset.html" "http://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/directory/asset.html"
```

If I visit /page/asset.html I get a 404 `NoSuchBucketThe specified bucket does not exist.`

I'm using HTTP as its just the development environment - I tested this by replacing the GCS URL with a URL from another development environment and that worked. I am thinking that there is some config that I've missed out for proxying GCS.

Note that the GCS URLs are public and can be visited without authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this issue

The problem is that I had `ProxyPreserveHost On` as it was serving some of my other proxies, but to access GCS we want to switch that off.
Now I can access the assets fine.

So my code looks like:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /first/proxy https://external.com/fproxy/
ProxyPassReverse /first/proxy https://external.com/fproxy/
ProxyPreserveHost Off
ProxyPass "/page/asset.html" "http://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/directory/asset.html"
ProxyPassReverse "/page/asset.html" "http://storage.googleapis.com/my-bucket/directory/asset.html"
```